# Setting Div's Position does not work with IE/FireFox

Tags: jquery, css, html, position

I have this code

I have number of issues,

first of all in FireFox 16.0.2 it does not show the second div , it also does not show the text "Hey all"
in IE it yes works but it sticks divs to each others and it does not show the text "Hey all"
I think Divs` positions are not set right
I tried to change position by both ways jQuery/css ..

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<style>
#11r5p6v8z9 {
position:fixed;
top:25px;
left:295px;
}

#11l6z9y3u6 {
position:fixed;
top:50px;
left:50px;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

//$("#11r5p6v8z9").css({ position: "fixed", top:25px;, left:295px;});
//$("#11l6z9y3u6").css({ position: "fixed", top:25px;, left:295px;});

//$("#11r5p6v8z9").offset({ top:25px; , left:295px;});
//$("#11l6z9y3u6").offset({ top:50px; , left:50px;});


});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="content">


<div id="11r5p6v8z9" style="border:1px dotted #f00;width:660px;height:410px;">
<iframe type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed    /Af1_73K8J5g" frameborder="0">
</div>
<div id="11l6z9y3u6" style="border:1px dotted #f00;width:660px;height:410px;">
<iframe type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed    /qjpjudx9_mU" frameborder="0">
</div>
Hey all

</div> <!-- content !-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here is the fiddle you could have made too http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/FBJNY/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ID's may not start with a number.  Your CSS Rules have a number so I think that is why you are getting invalid results.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html

Comment: I changed the divs names to begin with char , I got same result ,

Comment: @eawedat It worked for me. Did you remember to update both the HTML and the CSS.

Comment: @Scott, which browser r u using?

Comment: @mplungjan yes it shows me only one div/iframe video of youtube while I should get two & the text "Hey all"

Comment: And that is after I changed the IDs.

Comment: It appears that your comment tag is breaking jsFiddle.  Please change <!-- content !-->  to <!-- content --> and see if the behavior remains.

Comment: @mplungjan could you take a look at my code above please... it should show two divs/iframes that contains youtube's clips and a text message "Hey all" , in the fiddle you gave me I can see only one div/iframe.. I do not see the another div/iframe , and I do not see the text "Hey all"

Answer (score 2):

Can you try changing your id names as to my understanding id's cannot start with numbers [ids-cannot-start-with-a-number](http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/)

Jsfiddle code with some corrections - [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/anmolsaraf/gQLpQ/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#a11r5p6v8z9").css({ position: "fixed", top:'25px', left:'295px'});
$("#a11l6z9y3u6").css({ position: "fixed", top:'25px', left:'295px'});

$("#a11r5p6v8z9").offset({ top:'25px', left:'295px'});
$("#a11l6z9y3u6").offset({ top:'50px',  left:'50px'});


});
```

Comment: There are lot of mistakes in the jquery code regarding using single quotes instead of semi colon in css method. I have created a jsfiddle and tried correcting some of them, still there is one permission denied error for the iframe i guess. You can see the error in firebug console. The jsfiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/anmolsaraf/gQLpQ/4/ you can edit and check your code here

Comment: thank you:) very much , actually I was missing / for iframe </iframe> that did not allow to show everything under it.. but right now i am facing another problem which is in FF divs in some position and in IE in different position while I need them stick ,, same view/position in different browsers

Comment: Which version of IE are you using, I am seeing same results in ff16 and ie9 ?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `</iframe>`

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/FBJNY/

```
<div id="content">


<div id="x11r5p6v8z9" style="border:1px dotted #f00;width:660px;height:410px;">
    <iframe type="text/html" width="640" height="390" 
      src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Af1_73K8J5g" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="x11l6z9y3u6" style="border:1px dotted #f00;width:660px;height:410px;">
    <iframe type="text/html" width="640" height="390" 
      src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/qjpjudx9_mU" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
Hey all

</div> ​
```

Comment: wow that's working now :) thank you very much,,,you're awesome.. last question please..why positions differ in different browser? if I browse my web in IE not the same with FF...is there a solution ? I need divs stick at same points they are in most browsers